# Exrin: ViewModel vs VisualState vs Model vs ModelState clarification

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, exrin

I've watched through the [Exrin tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCmetoNpL4M&t) multiple times and have looked through the [couple](https://github.com/exrin/ExrinSample) [different](https://github.com/maximrub/ExrinProviders/tree/master/Sample) [samples](https://github.com/exrin/Tesla-Mobile-App) online which are very helpful to getting started, but one thing I'm having a hard time understanding is the ViewModel vs VisualState vs Model vs ModelState approach Exrin uses and would like some clarification as to what types of properties/other items get stored in each and how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is a diagram of how it is setup.

[image]

Second, going through an example. Say you have an API that gets a list of items.

You would do this.

1. In your Model, create a method that calls the Service or API to get a list of items.
2. In your ViewModel, in OnNavigated/ICommand, or whatever event you want to call it from, make a call to the Model to get this list of items.
3. Store this list of items in a property in your VisualState
4. In your View in XAML, `{Binding VisualState.ListOfItems}`