# Exrin: How to setup two way binding between VisualState and ModelState

Tags: xamarin.forms, exrin

How is the binding between `ModelState` and `VisualState` changed from one way to two way?

In the [Exrin introduction on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCmetoNpL4M) and in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44170915/5245420), it is stated that there is a binding between the `ModelState` and the `VisualState` (specifically `ModelState` -> `VisualState`). It is also stated that the binding can be changed from one way to two way.

I did some looking around and did find a `BindingType` enum with the values being `OneWay` and `TwoWay`, but I was unable to find where to utilize these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VisualState you can add this attribute to any property.

```
[Binding(BindingType.TwoWay)]
public int PropertyName { get { Get<int>(); } set { Set(value); } }
```

If there is no attribute it defaults to OneWay binding.